# Почему CHECK не работает в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> create table t (x int check (x>0));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.44 sec)

mysql> insert into t value (-1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> create table t1(x int, constraint namec check (x>0));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.28 sec)

mysql> insert into t1 value (-1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
```

Почему я не получаю никаких ошибок/предупреждений о том, что добавляемое мной значение в таблицу не удовлетворяет CHECK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что MySQL **игнорирует** это объявление. Он не поддерживает таких ограничений.

> The `CHECK` clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.
>
> — [MySQL Reference Manual по `CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

Вместо них предлагается использовать триггеры.

---

*Это перевод [ответа](http://[%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4][1]) на вопрос [**CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working) на StackOverflow.*

*См. также [аналогичный вопрос на DBA.SE: **check constraint does not work?**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/9662)*